# Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to implement runtime permission asking from the user using my app for the first time. Here is the code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            new masterdb(getApplicationContext());
            new checkRegistration().execute();
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        //initialize database
    }
```

But my app crashes with application not responding. The logcat shows something like this :

> Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method myPackageName.Lib.hasPermission
>   09-16 11:46:54.969 3763-3763/myPackageName W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 170: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I

The thing here is , this code shouldn't even run (checking for permission) in android Kitkat. But still I get this log. and when I move my code out of the if block of sdk version check it runs fine.

Comment: i am also getting same warning ...did you find any solution ?

Comment: Using ContextCompat instead of ActivityCompat solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Please try use this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      for (String permission : permissions) {
          int phoneStatePermission = Context.checkSelfPermission(permission);
          if (phoneStatePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           }
      }
}
```

Comment: don't know what difference does it make, it is exactly the same code